# Why and when should a comma be used at the end of a block?

Tags: syntax, rust, idioms

There many cases in Rust when a block of code can end with or without comma.
For example:

```
enum WithoutComma 
{
    x,
    y
}
```

or

```
enum WithComma
{
    x,
    y,
}
```

There are also other examples with `match`, etc. It seems that both variants lead to the same result. The only case I know where adding or removing a comma changes behaviour is the 1-element tuple declaration (which isn't a block):

```
let just_int = (5);
let tuple = (5,);
```

Why can one use a comma or not at the end of a block? Why is there such dualism in  thelanguage and what are the reasons for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you say, the only time a trailing comma is required is the 1-tuple pattern, type and construction `let (x,): (Type,) = (1,)`. Everywhere else, trailing commas are optional, have no effect, but are allowed for a few reasons:

- it makes macros easier: no need to be careful to not insert a comma at the very end of a sequence of items.
- it makes diffs nicer when extending a list of things, e.g. adding a variant to

  ```
  enum Foo {
      Bar
  }
  ```

  gives

  ```
  enum Foo {
      Bar,
      Baz
  }
  ```

  which is changing two lines (i.e. tools like `git` will display the `Bar` line as modified, as well as the inserted line), even though only the second actually had anything interesting in the change. If `Bar` started out with a trailing comma, then inserting `Baz,` after it is fine, with only one line changed.

They're not required (other than the 1-tuple) because that would be fairly strange (IMO), e.g.

```
fn foo(x: u16,) -> (u8, u8,) {
    (bar(x,), baz(x,),)
}
```

(I guess it would look less strange for `enum`/`struct` declarations, but still, it's nice to be able to omit it.)

Comment: After C++ where any addition or syntax sugar in language happens only when zounds of dead corpses appearance shows its importance it is hard to believe for me that reasons for this dualism with comma in Rust are only easier macro and diffs. However it seems you are right.