# Why is a trailing comma in a function call not a syntax error?

Tags: rust

I would expect this code to fail because the comma acts as a parameter separator. There is no second parameter and `foo` only accepts one parameter.

```
fn foo(_a: u8) {}

fn main() {
    foo(3, );
}
```

Comment: It is by design (I think I read somewhere that rust allows you to use or omit the trailing separator almost everywhere). Maybe this is relevant: https://github.com/rust-dev-tools/fmt-rfcs/issues/42 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163772/why-and-when-should-be-comma-used-at-the-end-of-a-block

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most languages accept trailing commas in comma-separated lists like argument lists or tuple or array literals. This is helpful if you split up a list across multiple lines, e.g.

```
let a = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
];
```

Since all lines are terminated by a comma, you can easily reorder the lines in your editor, and diffs will look cleaner in version control, in particular when adding further entries to the end of the list. This may not seem like a strong reason to allow the trailing comma, but since allowing the traling comma never hurts, it is good enough as a rationale.

Note that macro invocations in Rust don't always allow the trailing comma.

Other languages have a history of becoming more permissive for the trailing comma over time. JavaScript always allowed a trailing comma in array literals. They allowed it for object literals in EcmaScript 5, and for function parameter lists in EcmaScript 2017, while standard JSON still does not allow trailing commas. Python did not allow a trailing comma after `*args` and `**kwargs` until recently, but now they are allowed as well.

Comment: Yeah, in macros you can choose what separates parameters: `$($foo:ident),*` refers to 0 or more repetitions of an identifier followed by a comma, which needs the comma or else it doesn't work.

Comment: It also makes code generation easier with `macro_rules` or other other tools because you don't have to treat the last element of a list different than the rest. Every element in the list can have the trailing comma.