# Why do we call the vec macro using square brackets instead of the parenthesis it is defined with?

Tags: rust, macros

I am learning Rust macros and am confused about the syntax while using `vec`. The [source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.35.0/src/liballoc/macros.rs#L38-L46) implementing `vec!`:

```rust
macro_rules! vec {
    ($elem:expr; $n:expr) => (
        $crate::vec::from_elem($elem, $n)
    );
    ($($x:expr),*) => (
        <[_]>::into_vec(box [$($x),*])
    );
    ($($x:expr,)*) => (vec![$($x),*])
}
```

Let's forget the standard way to use it:

```rust
let v0 = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

If we look at the source code, shouldn't we use it like below?

```rust
let v1 = vec!(3; 1);
let v2 = vec!(1, 2, 3);
```

Why do we use `[]` instead of `()` in `v1` and `v2` compared to `v0`?

Comment: Your second question is answered by [Why and when should be comma used at the end of a block?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163772/155423); third question is answered by [How to allow optional trailing commas in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43143327/155423)

Comment: I am so sorry and thanks for telling me that. I will change this now.

Comment: See also [Why is a trailing comma in a function call not a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53672206/155423)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you note, you can use parenthesis, square brackets, or curly braces to call a macro:

```
let a = vec!(0, 1, 2);
let b = vec![0, 1, 2];
let c = vec! { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Macros don't care about which of these syntaxes you use<sup>1</sup>. **Programmers** care about which syntax you use.

Rust's array and slicing syntax uses square brackets and `Vec`s are highly related to both of these. Using square brackets for constructing a `Vec` is simply the language convention. Rustfmt will automatically convert calls to `vec!` into square brackets.

---

**1** - There's a small interaction between which brace style you use when invoking a macro and semicolons. A macro used as an *item* or *statement* is required to end with a semicolon if it doesn't use curly braces:

```
macro_rules! dummy {
    () => {};
}

// Not OK
dummy!()

// OK
dummy! {} 

// OK
dummy!();
```